# Angular2 ng-dirty class is not set when ngModel value changes

Tags: forms, angular

I have the following form with html

```
   <h1>ng-dirty Test</h1>

   <form [formGroup]="myForm">
     <input required [(ngModel)]='myVar'  formControlName="myVar" />
   </form>
   myForm.controls.myVar.dirty: {{myForm.controls.myVar.dirty}}
   <br/>
   <a href="#" (click)="myVar='my value 1'">my value 1</a>
   <a href="#" (click)="myVar='my value 2'">my value 2</a>
   <a href="#" (click)="myVar='my value 3'">my value 3</a>
```

When I enter a value manually into the input field, I see `ng-dirty` is set as a class.

However, when I click the links to set the value, I do not see `ng-dirty` is changing.

https://plnkr.co/edit/C3Y4pE?p=preview

Does anyone know what the reason is?

Comment: Isn't that the behaviour you'd expect? If it's the model input changing, rather than the user's input (in this case I understand the latter triggers the former, but...) then they haven't dirtied the form.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I was expecting it differently. When a value changes and became visible to user, it should be dirty. not only by users interaction to browser.

Comment: to change the myVar of the form, you have to make something like myForm.controls.myVar.setValue("my value"). You are currently changing just myVar of ngModel like mentioned in a previous comment and I don't think that Angular can be aware of this trigger.

Comment: That doesn't make sense, because then the whole form would be dirty if you loaded in e.g. default data or a previous saved state. It's the user interaction that dirties the control.

Comment: Indeed good point. Probably, the only way to make it dirty programatically, is following: https://plnkr.co/edit/nODWja4mWVBYFS1e7wRW?p=preview (click on the first link)